# 'Ambiguous reference' when using joinWithSeparator to intersperse into array

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use joinWithSeparator to insert a separator element between the elements of an array. Based on the documentation, I should be able to do:

```
[1, 2, 3].joinWithSeparator([0])
```

to get:

```
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3]
```

Instead, I get:

```
repl.swift:3:11: error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
[1, 2, 3].joinWithSeparator([0])
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `joinWithSeparator` works only with strings - *Constraints : Generator.Element == String*

Comment: Not in my docs: `@warn_unused_result func joinWithSeparator<Separator : SequenceType where Separator.Generator.Element == Generator.Element.Generator.Element>(_ separator: Separator) -> JoinSequence<Self>`

Comment: @vadian there's also an implementation in an extension on `SequenceType`: `extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : SequenceType`

Comment: Yes, I see. I'm as confused as the compiler. That's the ambiguity. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`joinWithSeparator` does not work like this. The input should be a sequence of sequence i.e.

```
// swift 2:
[[1], [2], [3]].joinWithSeparator([0])
// a lazy sequence that would give `[1, 0, 2, 0, 3]`.

// swift 3:
[[1], [2], [3]].joined(separator: [0])
```

You could also intersperse by flatMap and then drop the last separator:

```
// swift 2 and 3:
[1, 2, 3].flatMap { [$0, 0] }.dropLast()
```

Answer (score 0):

See the example in the generated Swift header:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : SequenceType {
    /// Returns a view, whose elements are the result of interposing a given
    /// `separator` between the elements of the sequence `self`.
    ///
    /// For example,
    /// `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]].joinWithSeparator([-1, -2])`
    /// yields `[1, 2, 3, -1, -2, 4, 5, 6, -1, -2, 7, 8, 9]`.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func joinWithSeparator<Separator : SequenceType where Separator.Generator.Element == Generator.Element.Generator.Element>(separator: Separator) -> JoinSequence<Self>
}
```

If you think about how it works on an array of `String`, it's exactly the same.